# How ReplicationDriver works

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, replication

I am curious how com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver works.
I have configuration with 1master & 1slave.

I want to force some queries to JUST on slave.
But it selects DB randomly and sometimes run it on master.

Is it a way to force readonly connection to use just slave DB and never master?

Answer (score 0):

For the ReplicationDriver to know that queries can go to read-only slaves, two conditions need to be met:

```
Auto commit needs to be turned off. (*)
Connection needs to be set to read-only.
```